# File descriptor leaked on lvchange invocation. Logical volume in use

Tags: lvm

this is it,

I am trying to run lvchange but it breaks.

This is the command to run:

```
lvchange -a n cinder-volumes/volume-2a01973e-de1a-46df-877d-0fc6db05123f
```

and this is the error message I am getting:

```
File descriptor 10 (/dev/urandom) leaked on lvchange invocation. Parent PID 27401: /usr/bin/python2\n  Logical volume cinder-volumes/volume-2a01973e-de1a-46df-877d-0fc6db05123f in use.
```

How can I release my lvm logical volume?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The "File descriptor leaked" message is a red herring. Yes, there's a (minor) bug in there somewhere, but it's not stopping anything from working. Look further in the error message:

```
Logical volume cinder-volumes/volume-2a01973e-de1a-46df-877d-0fc6db05123f in use.
```

You can't change a logical volume to unavailable while it's still in use. You'll have to find whatever has it open and stop it. Almost certainly it's either mounted (most likely) or opened by some process (less likely). For the former, use `df` to find where it's mounted. For the latter, use `lsof`.